# Solr Indexing SQL record with duplicate uniqueKey

Tags: solr, lucene, full-text-search, solr4

We need a full-text search for a db with millions of records (music meta-data) and I've only been working on Solr for 2 weeks roughly, I need some help regarding indexing. I am using `DataImportHandler` and have SQL query that generates result like this:

[image]

As you can see in the attached image above, the `id` (Integer data type) is repeated in the SQL result also used for in `DIH` and when I set uniqueKey to `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>` solr overwites the values leaving only one record/row , in fact I think the last one processed which is the one with `countryCode` 'TL'.

When I first had this issue, I knew why solr was overwriting the value, its's normal so I thought of adding a global identifer to each record in db, a guid - without thinking things properly, I ended up up with same duplicates as you can see `charGuid` which is a uuid() from MySQL is duplicated.

But when I use the `charGuid` (String data type) as uniqueKey to `<uniqueKey>charGuid</uniqueKey>`, I get all records indexed and nothing is overwritten but of course duplicates are inevitable. The problem I for-see here is when I have to do an incremental update, solr will not be able to know which document to update exactly, In fact a quick test from admin console, revealed that the last or first record its find with that unique key is updated. - This is not acceptable.

I stumbled upon an article referencing `multiValued="true"`, I thought making the fields that represents a JOIN column in my SQL will do the trick, but it doesn't. I was hoping a record with id:10 will be returned with a List of `countryCode` but no.

I am just puzzled as to how to circumvent this issue and why I did not find a similar problem posted by someone.

If I don't get a meaningful answer, I guess I will have to use `charGuid` as `<uniqueKey>` which allows duplicate and then use [Solr Document Deduplication Detection](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Deduplication) to handle updates of my index but I want to believe, there is a better way.

**Update**
Here is my data-config.xml and schema.xml defination:

```
<entity name="albums" query="select * from Album">
            <entity name="track" query="select t.id as id, t.title as trackTitle, t.removed as trackRemovedDate, t.productState from Track t  where t.albumId='${albums.id}'"/>         
            <entity name="albumSalesAreaId" query="select asa.salesAreaId as albumSalesAreaId  from AlbumSalesArea asa where asa.albumId='${albums.id}'"/>
            <entity name="albumSalesArea" query="select sa.name as albumSalesArea from SalesArea sa where sa.id='${albumSalesAreaId.salesAreaId}'"/>            
            <entity name="salesAreaCountry" query="select sac.countryId as 'salesAreaCountry' from SalesAreaCountry sac where sac.salesAreaId ='${salesArea.id}'"/>
            <entity name="countryId" query="select c.id as 'countryId' from Country c where c.id = '${salesAreaCountry.countryId}'"/>
            <entity name="countryName" query="select c.name as 'countryName' from Country c where c.id = '${salesAreaCountry.countryId}'"/>                         
        </entity>

**Schema.xml**
<!--new multivalue fields -->
<field name="albumSalesArea" type="int" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="albumSalesAreaId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="salesAreaCountry" type="int" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="countryId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="countryName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

When I compare my solr response with SQL result, I see countryCode but solr has none, only returned

```
"albumSalesAreaId": [
          1,
          3
        ],
```

Not sure why country etc not showing up.

### Update 2

*data-config.xml*

```
<document name="content">
        <entity name="albums" query="select * from Album">          
            <entity name="tracks" query="select t.id, t.title, t.removed, t.productState from Track t  where t.albumId='${albums.id}'">         
                <field column="id" name="id" />
                <field column="title" name="trackTitle" />
                <field column="removed" name="trackRemovedDate" />
                <field column="productState" name="trackProductState" />
            </entity>           
            <entity name="albumSalesAreaIds" query="select salesAreaId  from AlbumSalesArea  where albumId = '${albums.id}'">               
                <field column="salesAreaId" name="albumSalesAreaId"/>
            </entity>
            <entity name="albumSalesAreaNames" query="select name  from SalesArea  where id = '${albumSalesAreaIds.salesAreaId}'">
                <field column="name" name="albumSalesArea"/>
            </entity>               
            <entity name="salesAreaCountryIds" query="select countryId from SalesAreaCountry where salesAreaId ='${albumSalesAreaIds.salesAreaId}'">                    
                <field column="countryId" name="countryId" />
            </entity>   
            <entity name="salesAreaCountry" query="select name from Country where id ='${salesAreaCountryIds.countryId}'">                      
                <field column="name" name="countryName" />
            </entity>
            <field column="title" name="albumTitle"/>   
            <field column="removed" name="albumRemovedDate"/>  
            <field column="productState" name="albumProductState" />            
        </entity>   
    </document>
```

*schema.xml*

```
<field name="catchall" type="text_general" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>      
<field name="publisher" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>  
<field name="uuid" type="binary" indexed="false" stored="true"/>
<field name="trackRemovedDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="albumRemovedDate" type="tdate" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="trackProductState" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="albumProductState" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="countryCode" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/> 
<field name="albumTitle" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="trackTitle" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="guid" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<!--new multivalue fields -->
<field name="albumSalesAreaId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="salesAreaCountry" type="int" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="countryId" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="countryName" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="albumSalesArea" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

*sample solr response for id:5*

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 1,
    "params": {
      "indent": "true",
      "q": "id:5",
      "_": "1383221233535",
      "wt": "json"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 1,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "5",
        "catchall": [
          "5",
          "Test Album 5",
          "2011-10-21 00:00:00.0",
          "[B@261ca3cb",
          "Test Track 1",
          "Ya man 2",
          "2011-10-17 16:21:29.0",
          "1",
          "1450412569164513280"
        ],
        "albumTitle": "Test Album 5",
        "albumRemovedDate": "2011-10-21T00:00:00Z",
        "uuid": "6oT/MMl+RDaPyKpGK1KN0w==",
        "trackTitle": [
          "Test Track 1",
          "Ya man 2"
        ],
        "trackRemovedDate": "2011-10-17T16:21:29Z",
        "albumSalesAreaId": [
          1
        ],
        "_version_": 1450412569164513300
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

*SQL result for id:5*

[image]

`trackTitle` and `albumSalesAreaId` seem to be correct but not sure why others not been included however if hard code the `albumSalesAreaNames` entiy with `from SalesArea  where id = 1`, then I get `albumSalesArea` field added to result, so it seem like `from SalesArea` `where id = '${albumSalesAreaIds.salesAreaId}'"` is returning null, also confirmed from by 'IN' test earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks really a problem simply solved with a multivalued field. 
If you use multivalued field in this structure  what you will obtain is one document with ID=10, all the duplicated values will just be there once and all other fields will be multivalued. For example the NAME field will contain 4 different countries and so the country_code.

have a look at this article on how to structure your dataimportHandler to achieve this:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler#Full_Import_Example

basically you need one query for each multivalued field:

```
<dataConfig>
<dataSource driver="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" url="jdbc:hsqldb:/temp/example/ex" user="sa" />
<document name="products">
    <entity name="item" query="select * from item">
        <field column="ID" name="id" />
        <field column="code" name="code" />

        <entity name="countryName" query="select name from countrytable where item_id='${item.ID}'">
            <field name="name" column="description" />
        </entity>
        <entity name="countryCode" query="select countryCode from countrytable where item_id='${item.ID}'">              
        </entity>
    </entity>
</document>
```

Comment: This is what I had envisaged when I stumbled upon multivalue=true article as mentioned above, I will do some more digging and definitely, I will be back to report on outcome, thanks for at least giving me some tip. Cheers

Comment: I am not sure how to make the field a multivalued in SQL query, I tried doing select entity.id, entity2.*, entity3.* etc, I cannot give these selected fields/colums an alias to macth fieldname so I am not sure how to map the fields as multivalue in schema.xml. Am I correct to say that the select coulmns cannot be fields, e.g entity2.id, enity2.name ? hence I opted for entity2.*, entity3.* ...

Comment: check the updated answer. I added an example. you have to make many queries

Comment: Hi again, 
I managed to get one of the select statement to show up as multiValued but can't seem to figure out the rest, my schema definition is same as the one that shows up, so I'll keep trying then come back to you. I have updated my data-config and schema, please have a look perhaps you can find something wrong.

Comment: I think you are using the wrong field names in the query. You write "select asa.salesAreaId as albumSalesAreaId" so the field is now called "albumSalesAreaId" but then you use the old field name in the next query: "${albumSalesAreaId.salesAreaId}". Change it with "${albumSalesAreaId.albumSalesAreaId}"

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that too, so I completely removed the alias and replaced with <field column="salesAreaId" name="albumSalesAreaId"/> in my next query I used the real column name or is that wrong? Also I changed my next query from WHERE id = '${albumSalesAreas.salesAreaId}' TO WHERE id IN '${albumSalesAreas.salesAreaId}' notice the 'IN' and SQL throws exception with " Unable to execute query: select name from SalesArea where id in '' Processing Document # 1" so it looks like '${albumSalesAreas}' is not loaded from previous query. Can you spot any error?

Comment: can you update the schema in your answer? I donøt think you should use IN. did you try the normal query with "=" first?

Comment: I managed to get it to work, I had to nest the entities, I will update my structure now for the benefit of others to see., thanks a billion.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

### SOLUTION

```
    <entity name="albumSalesAreaNames" query="select name  from SalesArea  where id = '${albumSalesAreaIds.salesAreaId}'">
        <field column="name" name="albumSalesArea"/>
    </entity>
    <field column="salesAreaId" name="albumSalesAreaId"/>
    </entity>
```